# Why numpy.dot fails to parallelize on ndarray with more than 2 dimensions

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, intel-mkl

I noticed a funny behavior of the `numpy.dot()` function. 
My Enterprise RedHat 6.7 box has 2 Xeon CPUs each of which has 12 cores. I run the following code snippets then check CPU utilization in `htop`

The following code uses all the cores on my server:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(1000, 1000)
b = np.random.rand(1000, 5)
z = a.dot(b) #or use %timeit a.dot(b) if you use ipython
```

**EDIT:**
Below is the screenshot of htop while running the code above
[image]

But as soon as I add one more dimension to `b` like below, only one core is utilized.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(1000, 1000)
b = np.random.rand(1, 1000, 5) #or np.random.rand(n, 1000, 5) where n>=1
z = a.dot(b) #or use %timeit a.dot(b) if you use ipython
```

**EDIT:**
Below is the screenshot of htop while running the code above
[image: Below is the screenshot of htop while running the code above]

Below is the configuration of my python environment from `import sys; sys.version`

```
'2.7.11 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:08:32) \n[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)]'
```

Below is the configuration info from `numpy.show_config()`

```
lapack_opt_info:
libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'iomp5', 'pthread']
library_dirs = ['/opt/anaconda2/envs/portopt/lib']
define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
include_dirs = ['/opt/anaconda2/envs/portopt/include']
blas_opt_info:
libraries = ['mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'iomp5', 'pthread']
library_dirs = ['/opt/anaconda2/envs/portopt/lib']
define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
include_dirs = ['/opt/anaconda2/envs/portopt/include']
openblas_lapack_info: NOT AVAILABLE
lapack_mkl_info:
libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'iomp5', 'pthread']
library_dirs = ['/opt/anaconda2/envs/portopt/lib']
define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
include_dirs = ['/opt/anaconda2/envs/portopt/include']
blas_mkl_info:
libraries = ['mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'iomp5', 'pthread']
library_dirs = ['/opt/anaconda2/envs/portopt/lib']
define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
include_dirs = ['/opt/anaconda2/envs/portopt/include']
mkl_info:
libraries = ['mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'iomp5', 'pthread']
library_dirs = ['/opt/anaconda2/envs/portopt/lib']
define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
include_dirs = ['/opt/anaconda2/envs/portopt/include']
```

Has anybody seen this before? I tend to think this is a bug rather than by design because there is obviously more work to do with one more dimension. Also, is there a way to force palatalization of numpy.dot?
Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**
I have found a workaround to speedup the calculation. Please see the code snippet below.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(1000, 1000) #in my program a variable
b = np.random.rand(100, 1000, 5) #b is a constant
z1 = a.dot(b)
c=b.swapaxes(0, 1).reshape(1000, 5*100) #the trick is to turn the 3d array into a 2d matrix 
z2 = a.dot(c).reshape(z1.shape) #then reshape the result to the desired shape.
np.allclose(z1, z2) #the results are identical but the computation of z2 is more than 10 times faster than that of z1 on my server.
```

However, I agree in the long run we should study the numpy code as @hpaulj has suggested and fix the issue (in the event it is a bug) once and for all.

Comment: share your check of htop, please !

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll have to study the C source code, such as in

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/2f7827702ef6b6ac4b318103d5c0dfe2ff6e7eb3/numpy/core/src/multiarray/cblasfuncs.c

`cblas_matrixproduct` has a lot of code that checks the dimensions of the 2 input array.  Toward the end there's a section that handles matrix * matrix multiplication.

```
(PyArray_NDIM(ap1) == 2 && PyArray_NDIM(ap2) == 2)
```

It looks like the calculation core is bracketed with `NPY_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS` and `NPY_END_ALLOW_THREADS`

Your MKL code probably works as a replacement for BLAS.

Now the trick is to find where a 3d array is being handled.  Somehow is it operating on slices, so that the BLAS code still sees a 2d array.

My guess is that the use of multiple cores is done in the BLAS/MKL code, not in the `numpy` code.  In other words, `numpy` code says (to the compiler), "it's ok to use threads and/or cores here", but not "here's how split it up among the cores based on array dimensions".

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/386639363233165bcba1f1ba7b10aff3c40d46b3/numpy/core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule.c

`PyArray_MatrixProduct2` appears to be the function that decides how to call the `BLAS` dot functions I found earlier.

The 2 2d matrix case appears to be handled with:

```
#if defined(HAVE_CBLAS)
if (PyArray_NDIM(ap1) <= 2 && PyArray_NDIM(ap2) <= 2 &&
        (NPY_DOUBLE == typenum || NPY_CDOUBLE == typenum ||
         NPY_FLOAT == typenum || NPY_CFLOAT == typenum)) {
    return cblas_matrixproduct(typenum, ap1, ap2, out);
}
```

otherwise it has to use code like (after making sure the correction dimensions are compatible):

```
NPY_BEGIN_THREADS_DESCR(PyArray_DESCR(ap2));
while (it1->index < it1->size) {
    while (it2->index < it2->size) {
        dot(it1->dataptr, is1, it2->dataptr, is2, op, l, ret);
        op += os;
        PyArray_ITER_NEXT(it2);
    }
    PyArray_ITER_NEXT(it1);
    PyArray_ITER_RESET(it2);
}
NPY_END_THREADS_DESCR(PyArray_DESCR(ap2));
```

where `dot = PyArray_DESCR(ret)->f->dotfunc;` has been defined based on `dtype`.

I'm not sure I've answered your question, but it is clear that code is complex, and simple reasoning about how you or I would divide the task does not apply.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt and insightful answer. I guess it will take me quite a while to read the code and pinpoint the exact problem even though you have greatly narrowed down the search.  I have found a workaround for my immediate needs but understanding the C code will certainly be of a great value in the long run.